# Magento join two collections

Tags: magento

I need to get data from:

```
$collection =  Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')
```

Also I need to get the `state` column value from `sales_flat_order` table.

How to join these two and get data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a join to the select object for the collection.  In this case it's pretty straight forward as the 2 tables involved (`sales_flat_order_grid` and `sales_flat_order`) are very easily linked by the `entity_id` column common to both tables:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection');
$select = $collection->getSelect();
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$select->join(
    array('order' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order')),
    'main_table.entity_id = order.entity_id',
    array('state')
);
```

Comment: How to filter using order created_at date?